# Forward slash in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I can't figure out why the following code doesn't behave as expected

```
"Hello/You/There".replaceAll("/", "\\/");
```

- Expected output: `Hello\/You\/There`
- Actual output: `Hello/You/There`

Do I need to escape forward slashes? I didn't think so but I also tried the following against my will ... didn't work

```
"Hello/You/There".replaceAll("\\/", "\\/");
```

In the end I realized I don't need a regular expression and I can just use the following, which doesn't create a regular expression

```
"Hello/You/There".replace("/", "\\/");
```

However, I'd still like to understand why my first example doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show more context? Are you assigning the return result to a new string? Also, I don't think you need to escape it in the replacement string either.

Comment: You do have to escape the replacement :p ruakh's answer hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The problem is actually that you need to double-escape *backslashes* in the replacement string. You see, `"\\/"` (as I'm sure you know) means the replacement string is `\/`, and (as you probably don't know) the replacement string `\/` actually just inserts `/`, because Java is weird, and gives `\` a special meaning in the replacement string. (It's supposedly so that `\$` will be a literal dollar sign, but I think the real reason is that they wanted to mess with people. Other languages don't do it this way.) So you have to write either:

```
"Hello/You/There".replaceAll("/", "\\\\/");
```

or:

```
"Hello/You/There".replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\/"));
```

(Using [`java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29).)

Comment: +1 And reading the Javadoc is no help either, as it implies it should work without the double-escape.

Comment: I did run across `Matcher.quoteReplacement` but didn't read enough of the documentation to realize that backslashes also must be escaped.

Comment: You can see this link and the answer and comment threads to understand deeper about this. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875852/why-string-replaceall-in-java-requires-4-slashes-in-regex-to-actually-r/

Comment: @coder91: That question is actually about something different: it's about the well-known (and well-understood) fact that you need to double-escape certain things in the regex-string. This one is about the little-known (and more-surprising) fact that you also need to double-escape certain things in the replacement-string.

Comment: Similarly to split a string by '/' you will need '\\/' as the splitter.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh: If your comment displayed how you meant it to, then -- that's not true. If your comment is missing some backslashes, then -- that's true, but not "similar".

Answer (score 2):

Double escaping is required when presented as a string.

Whenever I'm making a new regular expression I do a bunch of tests with online tools, for example: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

That website allows you to enter the regular expression, which it'll escape into a string for you, and you can then test it against different inputs.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a reason behind why all these are messed up. A little more digging deeper is done in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875852/why-string-replaceall-in-java-requires-4-slashes-in-regex-to-actually-r/) and might be helpful to understand the reason why "\\" behaves like this.

Comment: Not really, I know I have to escape backslashes in JAVA, and that I have to double escape them in a JAVA regex, but the real problem is that single escaping should be enough in the replacement string since that's not a regex and the \ is not a special character