# Escape Forward Slash While Creating FIle Java

Tags: java, file, escaping

I am creating some files and file names are being fetched from database.

There is a file name called

> CUA/ICOR Digital Collection.

But, because of forward slash, "CUA" is getting treated as directory.

I have found [Forward slash in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575116/forward-slash-in-java-regex)

and  I have tried:

```
String fileName = "CUA/ICOR Digital Collection";
fileName = fileName.replaceAll("/", "\\\\/");  // OP: CUA\/ICOR Digital Collection But No success

fileName = fileName.replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\/"));  // OP: CUA\/ICOR Digital Collection But No success

fileName = fileName.replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\/"));  // OP: CUA\\/ICOR Digital Collection But No success

File file = new File(exportPath, fileName + ".xls");
```

I am getting

```
File Not Found Exception At 'C:\export\CUA\ICOR Digital Collection.xls'
```

So, Now I doubt is it possible ?

Comment: Can you have a backslash in the filename?

Comment: You could try an URL `file:...\\/..`; or quotes `"\"CUA/ICOR...\""`.

Comment: @RNJ - Nope. No slashes of any kind in Windows file names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows, a file can't contain `/\:*?"<>|`

You're better off converting the `/` character to something like an underscore `(_)`

Comment: ANd What about Linux, I am teting it on Windows but have to run in Linux

Comment: Every OS i'm aware of (Windows and all *nix variants, including Linux and likely OSX) interprets `/` as a directory separator, and consequently doesn't allow it in file names except where it's used as a directory separator.

Comment: I think in *nix the `/` is invalid/reserved for file separator.  I would do the same replacement regardless of OS.

Comment: @cHao: Oh I remember Yes, / is file separator in Linux. I guess I have to convert the `/`char to something like an underscore

Comment: @Jeff: Pretty much.  AFAIK the only two chars not allowed in a file's name in Linux are NUL (`'\0'`) and slash.

Comment: @cHao - I Windows, the `/` is not a path separator; it is the start of a switch. So `dir/w` in Windows (no space needed) is like `ls -l` in *nix.

Comment: @Ted: Dunno where you've been the past 17 years, but Win32 has accepted `/` as a path separator (probably internally converting it to `\\`, but who cares) for quite some time now.  The only time it gets a little weird about it is outside quotes after a space.

Comment: Apparently, [it goes back even further than that](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23123-when-did-windows-start-accepting-forward-slash-path-separator).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `Windows`.... i **don't think your file name** can have variable like `\`

You can try converting that to a `space` or `underscore`....

So it would be like this...

`CUA_ICOR Digital Collection`

**OR**

`CUA ICOR Digital Collection.`