# String index out of range with replace all

Tags: java, replace

How can I replace mapDir surrounded by <> to a certain string?

```
  String mapDir = "D:\\mapping\\specialists\\ts_gpc\\";
  String test = "foo: <mapDir> -bar";
  println(test.replaceAll("<mapDir>", mapDir));
```

The above gives me a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

This code below for me, but I think pure java has to work as well.

```
static String replaceWord(String original, String find, String replacement) {
    int i = original.indexOf(find);
    if (i < 0) {
        return original;  // return original if 'find' is not in it.
    }

    String partBefore = original.substring(0, i);
    String partAfter  = original.substring(i + find.length());

    return partBefore + replacement + partAfter;
}
```

Comment: You need to quote (Pattern.quote) the first argument of replaceAll, as it is a regex.

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875852/why-string-replaceall-in-java-requires-4-slashes-in-regex-to-actually-r/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need replaceAll method as you are not using regex. Instead you could work with `replace` api like below:

```
String mapDir = "D:\\mapping\\specialists\\ts_gpc\\";
String test = "foo: <mapDir> -bar";
System.out.println(test.replace("<mapDir>", mapDir));
```

Comment: Exactly. That `all` in `replaceAll` does not mean, that it replaces all occurrences of the searched string, whereas `replace` replaces only the first one. They both replace *all* occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

`replaceAll` in `String` uses a regex, as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

Thus, you should escape your replacement string like this:

```
String mapDir = "D:\\mapping\\specialists\\ts_gpc\\";
String test = "foo: <mapDir> -bar";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("<mapDir>", Matcher.quoteReplacement(mapDir)));
```

which gives the output:

```
foo: D:\mapping\specialists\ts_gpc\ -bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) works with regex, you need to re-escape the backslashes:

```
String mapDir = "D:\\\\mapping\\\\specialists\\\\ts_gpc\\\\";
String test = "foo: <mapDir> -bar";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("<mapDir>", mapDir));
```

Quoting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701868/1713801) answer:

> by the time the regex compiler sees the pattern you've given it, it
>   sees only a single backslash (since Java's lexer has turned the double
>   backwhack into a single one)