# Java String replaceAll - works in a wierd way for \

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have a string like this :

```
My word is "I am busy" message
```

Now when I assign this string to a pojo field, I get is escaped as below :

```
String test = "My word is \"I am busy\" message";
```

I have some other data in which I want something to be replaced by above string :

Let say my base string is :

```
String s = "There is some __data to be replaced here";
```

Now I when I use replaceAll :

```
String s1 = s.replaceAll("__data", test);
System.out.println(s1);
```

This returns me the output as :

```
There is some My word is "I am busy" message to be replaced here
```

Why that "\" is not appearing in after I replace. Do I need to escape it 2 times?

Also when use it like this :

```
String test = "My word is \\\"I am busy\\\" message";
```

then also it gives the same output as :

```
There is some My word is "I am busy" message to be replaced here
```

**My expected output is :**

```
There is some My word is \"I am busy\" message to be replaced here
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why String.ReplaceAll() in java requires 4 slashes "\\\\" in regex to actually replace "\"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875852/why-string-replaceall-in-java-requires-4-slashes-in-regex-to-actually-r)

Comment: @PM77-1 I am not trying to replace "\"

Comment: The "\" in the original `String` are there so the compiler ignores them, if you print the original `String` you will get `My word is "I am busy" message`

Comment: Why dont you use s.replace instead of s.replaceAll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String test = "My word is \\\\\"I am busy\\\\\" message";
String s = "There is some __data to be replaced here";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("__data", test));
```

To get the `\` in your output you need to use `\\\\\`

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use
>   Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

So you can use [Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String))

```
String test = "My word is \"I am busy\" message";
String s = "There is some __data to be replaced here";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("__data", test), Matcher.quoteReplacement(test));
```

Comment: I don't have control over adding backslash, I am getting the data from outside. Do you mean I escape it twice?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use four backslashes to print a single backslash.

```
String test = "My word is \\\\\"I am busy\\\\\" message";
String s = "There is some __data to be replaced here";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("__data", test));
```

**OR**

```
String test = "My word is \"I am busy\" message";
String s = "There is some __data to be replaced here";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("__data", test.replace("\"", "\\\\\"")));
```

**Output:**

```
There is some My word is \"I am busy\" message to be replaced here
```

Comment: I don't have control over adding backslash, I am getting the data from outside. Do you mean I escape it twice?