# How Java replaceAll operation works with backslashes?

Tags: java, replaceall

Why do I need four backslashes (`\`) to add one backslash into a `String`?

```
String replacedValue = neName.replaceAll(",", "\\\\,");
```

Here in above code you can check I have to replace all commas (`,`) from `\,` but I have to add three more backslash (`\`) ?

Can anybody explain this concept?

Comment: 2backslashes is not working??

Comment: Use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), not [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875852/why-string-replaceall-in-java-requires-4-slashes-in-regex-to-actually-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) states:

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll.

The documentation of [`Matcher.replaceAll(replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) then states:

> backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string

So to put this more clearly, when you replace with `\,`, it is as if you were escaping the comma. But what you want is really the `\` character, so you should escape it with `\\,`. Since that in Java, `\` also needs to be escaped, the replacement String becomes `\\\\,`.

If you are having a hard time remembering all this, you can use the method [`Matcher.quoteReplacement(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-), whose goal is to correctly escape the replacement part. Your code would become:

```
String replacedValue = neName.replaceAll(",", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\,"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape once for Java, and a second time for regexp.

`\` -> `\\` -> `\\\\`

Or since you're not actually using regular expressions, take `khelwood`'s advice and use `replace(String,String)` so you need to only escape once.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first escape the backslash because it's a literal (giving `\\`), and then escape it again because of the regular expression (giving `\\\\`).

Therefore this  -

```
String replacedValue = neName.replaceAll(",", "\\\\,");  // you need ////
```

You can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`-

```
 String replacedValue = neName.replace(",", "\\,");
```

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used for **escape sequence**

For example

- go to next line then use `\n` or `\r`
- for tab `\t`
- likewise to print `\`  which is special in string literal you have to escape it with another `\` which gives us `\\`

Now `replaceAll` should be used with a regex, since you're not using a regex, use `replace` as suggested in the comments.

```
String s = neName.replace(",", "\\,");
```