# Java: Single Backslash String - Why is "\\" illegal?

Tags: java, regex, escaping, backslash

I know that backslashes are used for character escapes, so I have to use two of them to write a single backslash.

But why doesn't this compile?

> "\\" => doesn't compile

BUT this:

> "\\\\" => "\"

Which \ escapes what?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `String r = "\\";` compiles fine. And please format your question correctly to avoid escape issues here, since you've actually said `"\\\\" => doesn't compile` (which is also incorrect).

Comment: This is not true. Put full code and (potential) error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why String.replaceAll() in java requires 4 slashes "\\\\" in regex to actually replace "\"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875852/why-string-replaceall-in-java-requires-4-slashes-in-regex-to-actually-r)

Comment: Yes, it is as I found out. (Explanation: 4th comment of answer one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the context. Some `String` methods don't use normal strings, they use **regular expressions**. In regular expressions, `\` is an escape character too, so to have a regular expression that corresponds to the plain `\` character, you have to write `"\\\\"`.

Comment: assumption goes too far. Nothing in question suggest such scenario

Comment: "\\" => doesn't compile - pretty much suggest the context.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it will compile, it will throw an exception at runtime when it will parse that regular expression but it will compile.

Comment: But the error message it will throw is actually that it can't compile the regular expression (because regular expression functions don't really directly process the expressions, they internally call `Pattern::compile()`), hence the confusion.

Comment: Well, my IDE gave me a very uncomprehensive error, so i didn't associate it with with a syntatical error in Regular Expressions but (wrongly) with a language error. Therefore I assumed that it won't compile as my IDE didn't let me compile it. But yes, I used it in String#replace, but I didn't know that this was important, so i left it out.