# (Java) To replace with a slash, why are 4 slashes required in replacement argument of String's replaceAll method?

Tags: java, replaceall

In Java, the string `"\\"` represents a single backlash, the first backslash being an escape character. Thus `System.out.print("\\")` prints `\`. However if `"\\"` is given as the *replacement* argument in method *replaceAll*, as in `"aba".replaceAll("b", "\\")`, the following exception is thrown: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing`.

Four slashes does the trick. Thus if one prints `"aba".replaceAll("b", "\\\\")` the result is `a\a`. But why is two slashes incorrect? Isn't the first slash the escaping slash, and the second slash the character to be escaped, just like in `System.out.print("\\")`? Notice that only one escaping slash is sufficient for other replacement strings passed to replaceAll. E.g. printing `"aba".replaceAll("b", "\t")` results in `a    a`.

Note: I'm using Java SE 9.

Edit: Some the questions suggested as duplicates are not duplicates. Please do not confuse this with the question of why four backslashes are needed in a regex to match a single backslash. This is not the same issue, as the second argument in replaceAll is obviously not a regex. You couldn't specify a replacement String with a regex because ultimately replacement needs to resolve to a literal String.

Comment: why use `replaceAll` which is using regex when all you need is `replace`

Comment: better dupe --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875852/why-string-replaceall-in-java-requires-4-slashes-in-regex-to-actually-r

Comment: The issue isn't present with replace. The problem isn't dependent on my simple regex though. You could rework the example with something more interesting that requires replaceAll.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that `replaceAll` method takes a [regualar expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) String which has its own meaning of `\` character so you have to escape it twice.

In simple words, reason that `"aba".replaceAll("b", "\t")` results in `a    a` is that `\t` is parsed to tabulation before regex, so when regex is parsed it only contains a tabulation.

Comment: I don't find this answer satisfying, as the second argument to replaceAll is not a regex. However I found at least a partial explanation, and it does have to do with the replacement string encoding more than just a literal String. From Oracle, "An invocation of this method of the form str.replaceAll(regex, repl) yields exactly the same result as the expression _Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)_" Then more is explained in Matcher's Javadoc here: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-)

Comment: from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String))  "The replacement string may contain references to captured subsequences as in the appendReplacement method.". I think this part is crucial as the replacement String is evaluated for further regex matching.