# Regular expression in java (java String)

Tags: java, regex, string

from this   ->  contractor:"Hi, this is \"Paul\", how are you?" client:"Hi ...." <-

I want to get just -> Hi, this is \"Paul\", how are you? <-

I need a regular expression in java to do that I try it but I m struggle with the inner quotation (\") is driving me mad.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? You could just strip out the redundant text around the keywords by using `.indexOf()` and `.substring()`

Comment: So briefly - you need to get the text inside a pair of double quotes `"the text to be matched"`, and this text may contain other double quotes preceded with a backslash `\"`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko . Yes Alex , I edit the question because editor doesn't skip inner quotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java supports [lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so vanilla regex:

```
"(.*?(?<!\\))"
```

Inside a Java string (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37329801/1225328):

```
\"(.*?(?<!\\\\))\"
```

The actual text will be contained inside the first group of each match.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8OXujX/2

---

For example, in Java:

```java
String regex = "\"(.*?(?<!\\\\))\"";
String input = "contractor:\"Hi, this is \\\"Paul\\\", how are you?\" client:\"Hi ....\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) { // or while (matcher.find()) to iterate through all the matches
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("No matches");
}
```

Prints:

```
Hi, this is \"Paul\", how are you?
```

Comment: That would include the final "Hi...." though. OP doesn't want that.

Comment: Yeah, first match should be taken I believe, at least in OP's example.

Comment: works fine with online regexp  editor but no on java code

Answer (score 1):

The regexp should be like this: `"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/7TFPSw/1)

It uses non-capturing group `?:`, matching any character `.` or a single character NOT in the list of double quote and backslash.

Comment: Not the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text1 = "contractor:\"Hi, this is \\\"Paul\\\", how are you?\" client:\"Hi ....\" <-";
    var regExWithQuotation = "contractor:(.+\".+\".+) client:";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regExWithQuotation);

    var m = p.matcher(text1);
    ;
    if (m.find()) {
        var res = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    var regExWithoutQuotation = "contractor:\"(.+\".+\".+)?\" client:";
    p = Pattern.compile(regExWithoutQuotation);
    m = p.matcher(text1);

    if (m.find()) {
        var res = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Output is:

"Hi, this is "Paul", how are you?"

Hi, this is "Paul", how are you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex, `(?<=contractor:\").*(?=\" client:)`

Description of the regex:

1. `(?<=contractor:\")` specifies [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `contractor:\"`
2. `.*` specifies any character
3. `(?=\" client:)` specifies positive lookahead for `\" client:`

In short, anything preceded by `contractor:\"` and followed by `\" client:`

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "contractor:\"Hi, this is \\\"Paul\\\", how are you?\" client:\"Hi ....\"";
        String regex = "(?<=contractor:\").*(?=\" client:)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hi, this is \"Paul\", how are you?
```