# "Redundant character escape" in Kotlin Regular Expression

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and tried some regular expression things.

What I want to do is just remove all `"comment"` formats in the string (including \" in middle).
Like this: `normal "commen\"t"` to `normal`

So I wrote this code:

```kotlin
val comments = fileContents.replace(Regex("\"(.?(\\\")?)*?\""), "")
```

and I got: `Redundant character escape '\\\"' in RegExp" warning.

I tried IDE quick fix thing, and it changed '\\\"' to '\"' which is not a happy result for me.

Also, the same regular expression worked without any warning or error in Python.
Here is the Python code:

```py
re.sub(r'"(.?(\\")?)*?"', "", _f.read())
```

How can I remove this warning?

Comment: You need to escape both backslashes, use `\\\\\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Use raw `String`s for creating `Regex`:

```kotlin
""""(.?(\\")?)*?"""".toRegex()
```

---

As you've written yourself, you need to escape some characters to actually get the regular expression you're looking for.
Disregarding any special characters that need escaping, I assume you try to reach the following pattern: `"(.?(\")?)*?"`.

To have an actual backslash character in your regular expression as literal character, you have to write four backslashes, [like in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875913/3160089).
This is because the backslash is both an escape character for regular `String`s as well as in `Regex`s.

The expression `"\\"` yields a string containing a single backslash. However, to get a literal backslash character in a regular expression, you have to escape it with another backslash character.
That is:
The expression `"\\\\"` turns into a `String` containing of two `'\'` characters, that is `"\\"`.
The `String` `"\\"` turned into a `Regex` becomes a regular expression containing a single backslash literal `\`.

You can see this more clearly by executing the following code:

```kotlin
println("\\\\")            // String with two backslash characters
println("\\\\".toRegex())  // Regex with single backslash literal

println("\\")              // String with single backslash characters
println("\\".toRegex())    // Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1 \
```

In general I'd recommend to use [raw strings](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/strings.html#raw-strings), whenever creating a regular expression in Kotlin. They're delimited by triple quotes (`"""`) instead of single quotes (`"`).
In raw string literals, the backslash character is not an escape character, thus you neither have to escape it (for the String) nor the single quotes.

Instead of `"\"(.?(\\\\\")?)*?\""` you can write `""""(.?(\\")?)*?""""`.

Additionally, you can use the [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions)
`fun String.toRegex(): Regex`, to convert your `String` to a `Regex` object, but that's just a question of preference.

All in all, your code could look like:

```kotlin
val fileContents = """normal "commen\"t" end"""

val regex = """"(.?(\\")?)*?"""".toRegex()
val comments = fileContents.replace(regex, "")

println(comments)   // prints "normal  end"
```