# Java Regex to replaceFirst occurence of (File.Separator or forwardslash(/) or backslash(\\)) in String

Tags: java, regex

I want to do what the title says , although i know how it can be done using the code below:

(Where `local` is a variable which represents a path):

```
String path = ( local.startsWith(File.separator) || local.startsWith("/") || local.startsWith("\\"))
                ? local.substring(File.separator.length(), local.length())
                : local;
```

---

I need to convert the above to regex expression so i am using:

```
path = local.replaceFirst("[" + File.separator + "/\\]", "");
```

---

Coming from `xml schema` where i was using regex expressions and looking on tutorials [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) it seems to me that it must work but it doens't at all, i get this error ->:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 4
[\/\]
    ^
```

---

**If** i change the code to the below,it works:

```
 local.replaceFirst("[" + File.separator + "/\\Q \\ \\E]", "");
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) is saying that `\` is a special character but:

There are two ways to force a metacharacter to be treated as an ordinary character:

- precede the metacharacter with a backslash, or
- enclose it within \Q (which starts the quote) and \E (which ends it).

This question was also read : [Forward slash in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575116/forward-slash-in-java-regex#9575170)

Comment: Just as a side note: make sure you fully understand your requirements; like: will your input contain different file separators; or will they be uniform; or on the other hand: will this code run on *one* specific platform; or is it supposed to run on many different ones? (and yes, I understand that this has going to answer your question)

Comment: @GhostCat Originally what i want to do is get the current directory of the `.jar` file which is tricky . It works if the user starts it with double click but it doesn't work if it starts it from command prompt , so i made a special method to do it . AFAIK Testing it on Windows the path is giving an extra `/` on the beginning that's why i need to use this regex . I have added and an answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java#7603444 )   .   If you know a better way i will be very glad :) It is intended to work on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error was :

By simply using `\\` it was replaced by `\` so i had only the special character.

The solution is to use `\\\\` so it is replaced by `\\` and the first `\` treats the second `\` as a character and not a special character.

Leaving this solution here in case somebody has the same problem..

Comment: Well, your problem has actually been asked and answered here before. And as there are no upvotes around (and probably no coming) ... you might consider to simply delete your question.