# Java Regex Matching Forward Slash and Word

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I want to the match the string `/word/test`. I tried `\/word\/(.*)` on regex101 and that works perfectly. It puts `test` in group1 and that's the part I want to extract.

But when I try this in Java I can't get it to work. This is my java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\/word\\/(.*)\\/");
```

But this comes out with no matches. I've been using [freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) to test out the java regex but have been unable to get anything to match. I think the forward slash is throwing things off but I've tried so many different. I've looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575116/forward-slash-in-java-regex) and tried `\\\\/` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You do not have trailing Slash in your original regex101, why do you use it in Java?

Comment: just tested on freeformatter with trailing slash on input (and some escaping slashes removed for their webform) and it worked.

Comment: more important question, what happened to your reputation score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/word/(.*)");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/word/(.*)/");`

The trailing `/` at the end of the pattern will not work for `/word/test` because it's looking for `/word/test/`. If you want the trailing slash to be optional, change it to something like:

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile(/word/(.*)(/)?");`

Comment: Why escape a `/`? It is not a special regex metacharacter.